# leaflet cloudflare 403 forbidden

Tags: angularjs, leaflet

I'm trying to embed a leaflet map in my html but I am seeing 403 errors in the Chrome console for a url like this 
 https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.0.2/images/data:image/png;…  I'm working on it here http://plnkr.co/edit/QrcKUz0PZRZRqUFaKfdq?p=preview.  I'm trying to get tiles from open street map

```
$scope.layers = {
                baselayers: {
                    osm: {
                        name: 'OpenStreetMap',
                        url: 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/osmfr/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
                        type: 'xyz'
                    }
                }
            };
```

Am I missing some credentials for accessing that page in my js or something?  I'm looking at a working example here http://plnkr.co/edit/0bTiyl?p=preview that doesn't provide any credentials.

The same problem occurs if I use

```
url: 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
```

Comment: Can I get some elaboration on the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the height in the leaflet directive to 480px and I can see the map now.